# How to create .mp4 file with custom frame rate

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, frame-rate

I have 10 files in a folder /nums/0-10.jpg. Want to create a three .mp4 files with different output FPS.

1. nums1.mp4 = should play 1 frame in every second
2. nums2.mp4 = should play 2 frame in a second
3. nums5.mp4 = should play 5 frame in a second

This code generates an mp4 with default settings

```
>ffmpeg -i /nums/%00d.jpg nums.mp4
```

Comment: Try this `ffmpeg -r 1 -i data/input-%4d.png -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 10 data/output.mp4` stolen from http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68770/converting-png-frames-to-video-at-1-fps

Answer (score 0):

With the option -r. If that parameter is set before -i it will act as "the rate according to which the images are read". However, when -r goes after the -i, it will act as "the rate of the output video stream".

You can define both, when you want the same rate for reading your images and writing them. More information [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images)

Comment: I am unable to understand 1/5 exactly. It would be really nice if you can provide me with three lines "ffmpeg <parameter>" to produce the required output files please ?